# R read.csv2 difference between encoding and fileEncoding parameters

Tags: r

What's the difference between encoding and fileEncoding parameters in the read.csv2 function?

I know that the documentation says that fileEncoding makes data to be re-encoded and encoding doesn't, but I don't understand what it means and when to use one or the other.

Thanks

Comment: Are you importing files with a different encoding than `UTF-8`?

Comment: Yes. Does it change the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

`encoding` is the encoding used for the input strings, and should be used if your filename is in a non-standard format.

`fileEncoding` is the encoding of the file.

---

From the documentation it doesn't become very clear at first, but there is some additional information in Value and Note:

> There are two approaches for reading input that is not in the local
> encoding. If the input is known to be UTF-8 or Latin1, use the
> encoding argument to declare that. If the input is in some other
> encoding, then it may be translated on input. The fileEncoding
> argument achieves this by setting up a connection to do the
> re-encoding into the current locale. Note that on Windows or other
> systems not running in a UTF-8 locale, this may not be possible.

Some additional information is under the documentation for `file`:

> When reading from a text connection, the connections code, after
> re-encoding based on the encoding argument, returns text that is
> assumed to be in native encoding; an encoding mark is only added by
> functions that read from the connection, so e.g. readLines can be
> instructed to mark the text as "UTF-8" or "latin1", but readLines does
> no further conversion. To allow reading text in "UTF-8" on a system
> that cannot represent all such characters in native encoding
> (currently only Windows), a connection can be internally configured to
> return the read text in UTF-8 even though it is not the native
> encoding; currently readLines and scan use this feature when given a
> connection that is not yet open and, when using the feature, they
> unconditionally mark the text as "UTF-8".

Comment: Unclear the difference between *encoding used for the input strings* and *encoding of the file*. The file is made of strings so the encoding of the strings is the encoding of the file

Comment: Input string is referring to the input passed to the function, e.g. `myfile = "inputstring.csv"; read.csv2(file=myfile)`.